# npm install jpm --global

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

Error in nodejs can anyone aware of what's the harm?
After the command **npm install jpm --global** ERROR.

**npm-debug.log**

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli
>   'install', 1 verbose cli   'jpm', 1 verbose cli   '--global' ] 2 info
>   using npm@3.6.0 3 info using node@v5.6.0 4 verbose stack Error: Failed
>   to replace env in config: ${APPDATA} 4 verbose stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:417:13 4 verbose
>   stack     at String.replace (native) 4 verbose stack     at envReplace
>   (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:413:12) 4
>   verbose stack     at parseField (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:391:7) 4 verbose
>   stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:334:17 4 verbose
>   stack     at Array.forEach (native) 4 verbose stack     at Conf.add
>   (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:333:23) 4
>   verbose stack     at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
>   4 verbose stack     at Conf. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:321:10) 4 verbose
>   stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:76:16
>   5 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs 6 error Windows_NT 6.1.7600 7
>   error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "jpm"
>   "--global" 8 error node v5.6.0 9 error npm  v3.6.0 10 error Failed to
>   replace env in config: ${APPDATA} 11 error If you need help, you may
>   report this error at: 11 error     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7468?

Answer (score 0):

cnpm or http://npm.taobao.org/

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Please use root permissions to install!